# Sort sql query result and concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables country,state and city

[image]

I need the results to be in the format

> ***country***  |  ***all the states belongs to the country separated by ',' ***  | ***all the city***
>   **belongs to the country separated by ','**

Also the states should not have any duplicates.
for eg:

> Badakhshan,Badakhshan,Badakhshan,Badakhshan,Badakhshan,Badgis,Badgis

should not occur.

I wrote a query to fetch the list

```
 with aggregatelist(countryname,statename,cityname) as 
 ( select c.name as countryname,s.name as statename,ct.name as cityname from countrymaster c inner join statemaster s  on 
  c.id=s.countryid inner join citymaster ct on ct.stateid=s.id group by c.name,s.name,ct.name
  )
```

But this will not return the desired format.

How can I do that without a temp table?

Comment: You have too much reputation to not know [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Stuff` and `FOR XML` Path to stimulate `group concat`

```
SELECT co.[Name], 
    STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ',' + st.[Name]
    FROM State st 
    WHERE co.Id = st.CountryId
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') As States,
    STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ',' + ci.[Name]
    FROM State st 
    INNER JOIN City ci ON st.Id = ci.StateId
    WHERE co.Id = st.CountryId
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') As cities
FROM Country co
```

Comment: I need the result to be concatenated and this has mentioned in the question also.

Comment: I've answered before this edit... I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I have made few modifications and it gave the output what I need. Thanks for the help. This is my final query. 
  SELECT  co.Name,
        STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ',' + st.[Name]
        FROM statemaster st 
        WHERE co.Id = st.CountryId
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1, 1, ''),
        STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ',' + ci.[Name]
        FROM statemaster st 
        INNER JOIN citymaster ci ON st.Id = ci.StateId
        WHERE co.Id = st.CountryId
        FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')
         As cities
 FROM countrymaster co

Answer (score 2):

if you have 3 tables as below, then SQL should look like:

```
create table city ( id number, name varchar2(1000),state number);
create table state ( id number, name varchar2(1000),country number);
create table ctry ( id number, name varchar2(1000),cc varchar2(10));

then SQL should look like:

SELECT a.name
      ,a.states
      ,b.cities
  FROM (SELECT c.id
              ,c.name
              ,listagg(s.name, ',') within GROUP(ORDER BY s.id) states
          FROM state s
          JOIN ctry c
            ON s.country = c.id
         GROUP BY c.id, c.name) a
 RIGHT JOIN (SELECT s.name
                   ,s.country
                   ,listagg(c.name, ',') within GROUP(ORDER BY c.id) cities
               FROM state s
               JOIN city c
                 ON s.id = c.state
              GROUP BY s.name
                      ,s.country) b
    ON a.id = b.country
```